# AR(2) model simulation with initial points

Tags: r, simulation, arima

I have an AR(2) model as *r_t=0.03+0.2r_{t-2}+a_t* with var(a)=0.1. I want to simulate this 1000 times with *r_0=-0.02* and *r_{-1}=0.01*. This is what I wrote but I'm pretty sure it's not correct, because when the first two values that it produces are not the ones I gave it. How do I do this?

```
mod1 <- arima.sim(list(ar=c(0,0.2), order=c(2,0,0)), n=1000, n.start=2, start.innov= c(0.01,-0.02), sd=sqrt(0.1))+0.03

> head(mod1)
Time Series:
Start = 1 
End = 6 
Frequency = 1 
[1]  0.2629583 -0.6263199 -0.2020755 -0.2865246 -0.3953399 -0.7285421
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I figured that what this function outputs is from the next point of what is given to it. for example, if you know r_5=0.01 and r_6=-0.02, and want to forecast 1-step and 2-step ahead with simulation, then `n=2` and `start.innov=c(0.01,-0.02)`. If you put `innov=c(0,0)`, what you get will be same as your analytical solution.